# Filter OneToMany Collection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I'm currently attempting to filter my OneToMany collection results, without much luck.

I've tried setting up a filter as stated in the [docs here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters#doctrine-orm-filters) to no avail.
With the following code, I only get an option to filter on the `Foos` collection **/api/foos** <- This request never actually finishes with the filter applied, even with pagination set to 1 per page.

[image]

[image]

Where I want/need it to be on **/api/foos/1?bar.isRetired=false** and to return a result of 1 'Bar' with many 'foos', but where 'foo.isRetired = false'

### Example

```
// config/packages/api_filters.yaml
services:
    filters.retired_filter:
            parent: 'api_platform.doctrine.orm.boolean_filter'
            arguments: [ { bars.isRetired: ~ } ]
            tags: [ 'api_platform.filter' ]


// src/Entity/Foo.php

/* @ApiResource(attributes={"filters"={"filters.retired_filter"}}) */
class Foo
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bars", mappedBy="foo") */
    private $bars;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->bars = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

// src/Entity/Bar.php

/* @ApiResource() */
class Bar
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    /* @ORM\Column(name="is_retired", type="boolean") */
    private $isRetired;
    /* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Foo", inversedBy="bars") */
    private $foo;
}
```

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

I'm using Symfony4 with Flex and API-Platform 2.1

Comment: @PolDellaiera I did at the time however I posted this 2 years ago and the whole setup of Api Platform is very different now. More importantly the documentation is far more complete and the filter system is now much more robust. If you check out the docs I'm sure you'll agree.